# Signify in UML that a class MIGHT inherit from another class

Tags: uml

For an assignment we're using UML.

It's basically modelling a recruitment system. My question is, I wish to show that a HR manager COULD be an interviewer in an interview. But since we cannot be sure that a HR manager is a Interviewer, I want to know if there is a notation for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he *could* be one, then you *must* inherit. Else you don't have access to `Intervier`'s properties.

To decide whether or not `HR-Manager` actually *is* an `Interviewer` you need language specific operations that check the type. Or you introduce a flag which tells that he now actually *is* one.

Alternatively it's possible to make an association as you did. So you work without inheritance. But then the multiplicity needs to be `0..1` and not just `1`.

It depends on the requirements which way you model it.

Comment: If `HR-Manager` inherits from `Interviewer` then it is always an `Interviewer`. There is no such thing as optional inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble onto something like *Optional Inheritance*, which doesn't exist in OO then that usually indicates that you are doing something wrong.

In this case I think the *something wrong* is to try and model user roles as user classes.

`HR Manager`, `Department head` and  `Interviewer` are all different roles a person may play.

This design pattern has been documented on many different places such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model)